# Removing small words in python from nested lists

Tags: python, list

In python I've a a list named list_1 for the purpose of this question.
Imbedded within that list is a number of smaller lists. 
I want to go through each of these lists one by one and remove any words that are smaller than 3 characters.
I've tried a number of methods and come up with nothing i can get working.
I thought i may be able to create a loop that went through each word and checked it's length, but i can't appear to get anything working at all.

Suggestions welcome.

Edit: Ended up using code

```
while counter < len(unsuitableStories): #Creates a loop that runs until the counter is the size of the news storys.

    for word in unsuitableStories[counter]:


        wordindex = unsuitableStories[counter].index(word)
        unsuitableStories[counter][wordindex-1] = unsuitableStories[counter][wordindex-1].lower()

        if len(word) <= 4:

            del unsuitableStories[counter][wordindex-1]



    counter = counter + 1 # increases the counter
```

Comment: What did you try so far? which error are you having? Show the code you wrote until now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nested list comprehension, like this

```
lists = [["abcd", "abc", "ab"], ["abcd", "abc", "ab"], ["abcd", "abc", "ab"]]
print [[item for item in clist if len(item) >= 3] for clist in lists]
# [['abcd', 'abc'], ['abcd', 'abc'], ['abcd', 'abc']]
```

This can also be written with [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) function, like this

```
print [filter(lambda x: len(x) >= 3, clist) for clist in lists]
```

Comment: I understand nested comprehension, but I'm having trouble 'pruning words' within nested lists. That's what I'm getting lost on, actually removing them from the list.

Comment: @DavidShepherd We pick elements only if they match this condition `if len(item) >= 3`. So that is our filtering condition :)

Comment: I understand what your getting at , but struggling to understand how i can code that. I appreciate you trying to push me in the right direction though.

Comment: @DavidShepherd Please check the other answer as well, that is straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an code example, not just printing.  Primitive but effective :D

```
lst = []
lst2 = ['me', 'asdfljkae', 'asdfek']
lst3 = ['yo' 'dsaflkj', 'ja']

for lsts in lst:
    for item in lsts:
        if len(item) > 3:
            lsts.remove(item)
```

EDIT:
The other answer is probably better.  But this one works too.